# Convert 2d CAD object to TIFF format using c++

Tags: c++, export, 2d, tiff, autocad

I am trying to export CAD formats (mainly 2D Autocad drawings) to TIFF format.

All I could find on the internet is how to convert image formats to Tiff ( pixels, colors..). But I'm looking to save geometry data (mostly 2D Autocad drawings) into TIFF format using C++98 and TIFF library and I have the following questions:

1. Does the tiff format allow such conversions?

   (I read something about possibility to include vector-based clipping path but i don't understand it very much)
2. If so can anyone help me on how to do it?

Comment: Yes, you can render a CAD drawing into a TIFF. But also yes, that's inevitably going to lose something--the TIFF is a rendering, so it's going to be at some fixed scale, from some fixed viewpoint. As to how to do it, you typically render it into a memory buffer roughly like you were going to display it on screen, then use a TIFF library to format that buffer of pixels into the correct format.

Comment: Let's just start with 2D...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have autoCAD, then you may somehow hack the "export to TIFF" button.

I found something that might help you [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/49c52f59-a272-4e47-b33d-3fee87ffd291/using-autocad-in-c?forum=vcgeneral) (searched *`c++ autocad export`*):

> Add reference to "`autocad/objectdbx` common 16 type library"
>
> ```
> _acadAPP = gcnew AcadApplication();
> AcadDocumentClass * _acadDocument = safe_cast< AcadDocumentClass * >(
> _acadAPP->Documents->Item( 0 ));
> _acadAPP->Visible = true;
> IAcadModelSpace ^_acadModelSpace = dynamic_cast< IAcadModelSpace *>( _acadDocument->ModelSpace);
> ```

It might be overcomplicated if you don't have it. If you read posts related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169390/open-source-cad-drawing-dwg-library-in-c-sharp) here on SO, you'll note that since AutoCAD is not open source, it's difficult to do anything without it.

Once this huge part is done - not sure it's feasible, then follow instruction on [libtiff.org](http://www.libtiff.org/libtiff.html), it looks like this:

```
#include "tiffio.h"
main()
{
    TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen("foo.tif", "r");
    ... do stuff ...
    TIFFClose(tif);
}
```